# mysql - how to insert data in a table which sort of holds the matrix of 3 other tables

Tags: mysql, insert, matrix

Let's say I have 3 mysql tables - `teacher`, `subject`, and `class`, each table having only two fields `id` and `name`

If every teacher can teach every subject in every class, what is a good way to insert this information using SQL into a fourth table to hold that data, if my fourth table has three fields for `teacher_id`, `subject_id`, and `class_id`

Just to make it clear by an example, if I had only two teachers (teacher.id 1 and 2), two subjects (subject.id 1 and 2) and two classes (class.id 1 and 2), data in the fourth table would look something like below.

```
teacher_id  subject_id  class_id
    1           1           1
    1           1           2
    1           2           1
    1           2           2
    2           1           1
    2           1           2
    2           2           1
    2           2           2
```

Comment: In the fourth_table, teacher_id, subject_id, class_id together make a composite key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are looking at a cross join or cartesian product.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join

In your case

```
SELECT teacher_id, subject_id, class_id 
    FROM teacher JOIN subject JOIN class 
    ORDER BY teacher_id, subject_id, class_id
```

With large sets of data this can take a while to return.

Comment: I made a few changes to that so that it corresponds with the information in my question --- SELECT t.id, s.id, c.id FROM teacher t JOIN subject s JOIN class c ORDER BY t.id, s.id, c.id

Comment: It does return what I want, so that I can do an `INSERT` using (I think) INSERT INTO fourth_table (teacher_id, subject_id, class_id) SELECT t.id, s.id, c.id FROM teacher t JOIN subject s JOIN class c ORDER BY t.id, s.id, c.id

Answer (score 1):

Do an insert with subselect of the cartesian product of the teacher, subject, class tables.

```
INSERT INTO fourth_table
(SELECT * FROM teacher, subject, class)
```